# eliminate gray background from component

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, custom-component

I'm trying to overlay a jpanel onto my custom background for my canvas. My background is a very complex thread-based gradient. Problem is that when I add a `JPanel` with a size of 400 by 600 (my screen resolution is a lot bigger), the rest of the canvas is washed out in gray. I've tried setting opaque to false and other supposed solutions, but none worked. Is there a way to create a complete custom JPanel or a way to eliminate this gray layer outside of the JPanel area?

**Edit:**

After setting the JPanel to red with dimensions of 400 x 600 and set at a position of 600 x 100 on the screen, the entire panel is filling the complete size of the canvas.

```
    JPanel ptest = new JPanel();
    ptest.setLayout(null);
    ptest.setBackground(Color.RED);
    ptest.setBounds(new Rectangle(600, 100, 400, 600));
    frame_.getContentPane().add(ptest);
```

I've tried different Layouts, but got the same results.

Comment: In principle you then have some error. Is the layout of the container to which you add the panel correct (for instance null - absolute)? Try by adding a red border to the panel, and set a green background. Maybe the container is responsible for the gray.

Comment: A screenshot would help here, and this is likely to be a layout manager issue.